# rails 4.0 handling empty mongodb result query through mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to go through Michael Hartl's rails4 tutorial using mongoid and mongodb instead of the normal database. I'm up to where I have to set up user signing in and signing out and here's the problem that I'm running into. Below is the code I'm using to check if the user's email is registered.

```
user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  # sign in and load user page
else
  flash[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
  render 'new'
  # error and re-render signin
end
```

Unfortunately I'm getting hit with a document not found because that's what is returned when the query turns up blank. It should go into the else but instead I'm getting a rails error page that's returning the mongoid error document not found. How do I avoid that and have the code execute what's in the else statement instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mongoid has `raise_not_found_error` settings option which forces mongoid not to throw error you mentioned above when set to false. More details could be found on the [documentation page](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html). So if you want to handle all the Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound errors in your application manually just add this line in your mongoid.yaml:

```
raise_not_found_error: false
```

If you want mongoid not to raise error just in the current action you could call rescue just after the find_by method call and then check the user variable for nil-ness:

```
user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase) rescue nil
if !user.nil? && ...
  ...
else
  ...
end
```